# Joining rows with similar fields

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables:

```
COUNTRY (land_name, land_code)
CONTINENT (land_code, cont)
```

I need to create two queries:

1. Get all Countries, that are in 2 continents (Assume that this is the only possibility, 
   there is no country that is in more than 2 continent). Output form (`land_name, Cont1, Cont2`)
   I tried to create a query, that at least takes the values from CONTINENT table:

   ```
   SELECT land_code, MAX (cont) AS "K1", MIN(cont) AS "K2"
   FROM CONTINENT 
   GROUP BY land_code;
   ```

   But in output I get the list of all countries, even they are only in one continent
2. Get the pair of countries that are in same continents (`land_name1, land_name2, Cont1, Cont2`)

> ```
> COUNTRIES (land_name, land_code, capital)
> Austria A Vienna
> Turkey TR Ankara
> Russia RU Moscow
> Italy I Rome
> France F Paris
> Egypt ET Cairo
>
> CONTINENTS (land_code, Continent, Percentage)
> ET Africa 90
> ET Asia 10
> F Europe 100
> RU Asia 80
> RU Europe 20
> TR Asia 68
> TR Europe 32
> ```

Comment: For the first part, investigate the `having` clause, but you need a join too. Not sure I understand the second part.

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes, for sure I need join, that was in order just to even look whether will it work without name, but it is not=( The second part is to give a pair of countries and pair of continents. For ex. (Turkey, Russia, Asia, Europe) -> Both countries are and in Asia and in Europe

Comment: @Begueradj Oh, have a goodnight=) It is okay... Hope so.

Comment: did you try the answer of Multisync above ?

Comment: @Begueradj yes I tried, but it doesn't work =(

Comment: Please, post the data structures of your 2 tables (the queries you used to create them so that i will use them and insert data into them and test my queries)

Comment: I used `
mysql> create table country (land_name varchar(20) not null,land_code int(5) not null, primary key(land_name));


mysql>  create table continent (land_code int(5) not null, cont varchar(20) not null, primary key(cont), foreign key(land_code) references country(land_code));` but i prefer to use your own schema

Comment: @Begueradj I edited post, and added the data from tables

Comment: thank you, but i mean the queries with which you created the 2 tables (like the ones i wrote above), i want to be sure you did not make a mistake (especially around the foreign key)

Comment: @Begueradj there is no any key =) It is just tables, that don't have connection.. Just for practicing)

Comment: that is the error my friend: i was astonished why all the solutions did not wor. You can not get what you want if you do not link your 2 tables with a foreign key referening the country table. It is impossible my friend. I gave you 2 queries above how to do that if you want to achieve what you want, otherwise it is impossible what you are asking to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 Assuming that there is no country that is in more than 2 continent, you may use this query:

```
select land_name, cont1, cont2
from (select c.land_name, min(t.cont) cont1, max(t.cont) cont2
      from country c join continent t on c.land_code = t.land_code group by c.land_name) t
 where t.cont1 != t.cont2;
```

2 All pairs of countries on the same continent:

```
select distinct t1.land_name, t2.land_name, c.cont
from  country t1
      join country t2 on t1.land_name < t2.land_name
      join continent c on c.land_code = t1.land_code
 where t1.land_code = t2.land_code;
```

If you need to show pairs of countries which have two continents in common you may try this:

```
select t1.land_name, t2.land_name, t1.cont1, t1.cont2
from (select c.land_name, min(t.cont) cont1, max(t.cont) cont2
      from country c join continent t 
           on c.land_code = t.land_code 
      group by c.land_name) t1
      join
     (select c.land_name, min(t.cont) cont1, max(t.cont) cont2
      from country c join continent t 
           on c.land_code = t.land_code 
      group by c.land_name) t2 
      on t1.land_name < t2.land_name     
 where t1.cont1 != t1.cont2
   and t1.cont1 = t2.cont1 and t1.cont2 = t2.cont2;
```

Comment: thank you for your replies. For the 1st one - it doesn't return any result, but if I change to WHERE T.CODE1=T.CODE2 then it returns all possible pairs. For 2nd one, it should return a pair of countries that are in same 2 continents. For Ex. (Russia, Turkey, Asia, Europe)=> both countries have parts in Asia and in Europe

Comment: @nlimits The first one should work fine. Are you sure you have a country which has two land_codes? the second one - it wasn't clear from your question that you need pairs which have two continents, my query returns pairs which have 1 continent in common

Comment: I have posted some data from my tables in question. Yes, that is my fault, that I didn't write clear. Anyway thanks. I understood that your query returns countries that have common continent. But in my case I need 2 common continents

Comment: @nlimits I've updated my answer regardint your structure - check the first query

Comment: first query now works good =))) But second one, still doesn't return any value, the one that you posted last

Comment: @nlimits But your structure looks a bit strange - in the continent table you don't have unique land_codes. It's not clear. In the country table you don't have a primary key. That's why in the queries above I need to compare strings.

Comment: @nlimits You're welcome. If you're practicing - I'd recommend you to learn about normal forms. In you case I had to compare strings to get the desired result, it's not a good practice. I'd create 3 tables: "country" with unique codes, "continent" with unique codes and "country_continent" which links (many-to-many) countries and continents. In this case your structure will be more flexible and won't contain any redundant data

Comment: actually I know abut normal forms, but that was in question, that use only this kind of tables. That made me a bit confusing.